# Android Connection Timeout on AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask

Trying to get this simple download and save image to work but i keep getting a Connection Timeout Exception.

As far as i am aware the web address should work

```
new DownloadImageTask();



private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String urldisplay = "http://masterzangetsu.eu/Apps/BandWallpapers/Blink182/1_thumbnail.png";
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");

        boolean success = false;

        // Encode the file as a PNG image.
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
            /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            success = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And heres the outoput

```
10-29 12:33:36.075: W/System.err(817): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to     masterzangetsu.eu/91.208.99.12 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
10-29 12:33:36.075: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
10-29 12:33:36.095: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
10-29 12:33:36.105: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-29 12:33:36.105: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
10-29 12:33:36.105: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
10-29 12:33:36.105: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
10-29 12:33:36.115: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
10-29 12:33:36.115: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
10-29 12:33:36.115: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
10-29 12:33:36.115: W/System.err(817):  at com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1.doInBackground(HttpUrlDownloader.java:51)
10-29 12:33:36.115: W/System.err(817):  at com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1.doInBackground(HttpUrlDownloader.java:1)
10-29 12:33:36.125: W/System.err(817):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-29 12:33:36.125: W/System.err(817):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-29 12:33:36.125: W/System.err(817):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-29 12:33:36.136: W/System.err(817):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-29 12:33:36.136: W/System.err(817):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-29 12:33:36.145: W/System.err(817): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
10-29 12:33:36.165: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
10-29 12:33:36.165: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
10-29 12:33:36.165: W/System.err(817):  at     libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-29 12:33:36.165: W/System.err(817):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-29 12:33:36.165: W/System.err(817):  ... 21 more
```

Full output http://pastie.org/8439940

and Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: have you set the permission to acces internet?

Comment: Indeed, added the permissions from the manifest

Comment: try using defaulthttpconnection and then setting the connection time out. it could be that due to device net connectivity the delay occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works successfully. I suggest you to check your internet connection.

Comment: so it does ... it must be something to do with the proxy where I was testing it. Thanks