# Download and Display Image from url in json in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to display user details in recycler view.

When i try to display my image it is not working.I have tried all possibilities. Following is my adapter class.

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
   private LinkedList<HashMap<String, Object>> myDataSet;
   Bitmap bitmap;
   MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
   String image;

public MyAdapter(LinkedList<HashMap<String, Object>> values) {
    myDataSet = values;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView userIdView;
    public TextView jobTitleNameView;
    public TextView employeeCodeView;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userIdView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.userId);
        jobTitleNameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobTitleName);
        employeeCodeView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.employeeCode);
    }
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
            parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final HashMap<String, Object> userDetails = myDataSet.get(position);
    String userId = (String) userDetails.get("userId");
    String jobTitleName = (String) userDetails.get("jobTitleName");
    String employeeCode = String.valueOf(userDetails.get("employeeCode"));
    image = (String) userDetails.get("image");

    ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    imageDownloader.execute(viewHolder);


    holder.userIdView.setText(userId);
    holder.jobTitleNameView.setText(jobTitleName);
    holder.employeeCodeView.setText(employeeCode);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myDataSet.size();
}
```

This is the class written inside this class for downloading image.

```
private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder,ViewHolder,ViewHolder>{

    @Override
    protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        viewHolder = params[0];

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(image);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder result){
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
   }
 }
```

Can someone help me with this....

Please find the log below

```
    03-24 16:27:48.421 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.scri8e.com/208.87.227.250 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    03-24 16:27:48.421 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
    03-24 16:27:48.421 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    03-24 16:27:48.421 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
    03-24 16:27:48.421 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
    03-24 16:27:48.421 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.example.rini.listviewandroid.MyAdapter$ImageDownloader.doInBackground(MyAdapter.java:94)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at com.example.rini.listviewandroid.MyAdapter$ImageDownloader.doInBackground(MyAdapter.java:77)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    03-24 16:27:48.422 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
    03-24 16:27:48.423 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
    03-24 16:27:48.423 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    03-24 16:27:48.423 19806-20764/com.example.rini.listviewandroid W/System.err:   ... 17 more
```

Comment: I highly recommend Glide! It's built with many features and saves you lot of pain (memory leaks, caching, download the image). As long you don't need special solution, I would use it.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not a direct solution could I recommend using a Library like Picasso and Glide? It will significantly reduce the number of lines of code. Here are some links to the libraries

Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Glide: https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-getting-started

Your onBindViewHolder would then look something like this

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final HashMap<String, Object> userDetails = myDataSet.get(position);
    String userId = (String) userDetails.get("userId");
    String jobTitleName = (String) userDetails.get("jobTitleName");
    String employeeCode =     String.valueOf(userDetails.get("employeeCode"));
    image = (String) userDetails.get("image");

    //With Picasso 
    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(viewHolder.imageView);

    //With Glide 
    Glide.with(context).load(image).into(viewHolder.imageView);

    holder.userIdView.setText(userId);
    holder.jobTitleNameView.setText(jobTitleName);
    holder.employeeCodeView.setText(employeeCode);
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible without these libraries?

Comment: No its possible, i'm just suggesting these libraries so you can cut down on the code + they allow you to do more with the images. Like i said its not an answer it was just a suggestion. I Would have put it as a comment however i just wanted to give you a code example to show you how much it can cut the code down by.

Answer (score 0):

Try modify `ImageDownloader` like this. I am not sure, but it should work;

```
private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap> {
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private String image;

    public ImageDownloader(ViewHolder viewHolder, String image) {
        this.viewHolder = viewHolder;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(image);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
        if(bitmap != null) {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Than in adapter:

```
ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader(viewHolder, image);
imageDownloader.execute();
```

Comment: I am getting this exception  `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.scri8e.com/208.87.227.250 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

Comment: try to get image like this `InputStream in = new java.net.URL(image).openStream();
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);`

Comment: even after adding this no difference

Comment: can you send me full log stack?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658598/android-connection-timeout-on-asynctask) Here similar code. Read it

Comment: added it to question

Answer (score 0):

There might cause problem to decode bitmap like this:

```
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

if some bytes are wrong, the result will return null.

You can try like below:

```
private static Bitmap urlFetch(Context context, String url) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        int rspCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (rspCode != 200) {
            return null;
        }
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        long total = conn.getContentLength();
        try {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(
                        inputStream));
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
}


static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

Basically it will skip wrong byte to prevent all the bitmap went wrong.

By the way, `Imageloader` is a complex method, you need to consider memory consuming(handling bitmap is really easy to cause OOM), cache and reuse the bitmap as `file` or `lrucache`, downlaoding multiple pictures at the same time without degrading the UX(thread pool), so I recommend you to use a third-party library to handle this job. [Universe-image-loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) .xactly meant for what you are looking for .I have been using this since long,highly custom-able.You can even choose to either cache the images for faster loading from network or from storage.An as simple as that

> Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);